# In Swift, how to optimize dictionary checking/assignment?

Tags: swift, swift2

Please see following code:

```
let myDict = [Int:Object]()

func task(newId: Int) {

    var newObj = myDict[newId]
    if (newObj == nil) {        // Question (1)
        newObj = Object()
        myDict[newId] = newObj

        newObj!.doSomething()   // Question (2)
    }
}
```

Question (1): I am trying to see if an object associated with `newId` already exits in `myDict`. If not, create one and assign it in `myDict`. I am wondering if any better way to do this? It doesn't look very "swift" right now :)

Question (2): I have to add `!` here, but I feel kind of odd that I still have to force unwrapping it even I just created a new object one line above. (no Failable Initializer in `Object`)

Any advise to help me/correct me to know better about Swift is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll though I'd add some notes w.r.t. your code that I find important to point out. After these notes, I'll add two quick answers to your question.

---

First, lets just analyse your code as it is. We note that you have not told us the type of `Object`, which means that the behaviour of the code is not well-defined, in the sense that it will behave differently depending on if `Object` is of value- of reference-type.

For this, we'll look a at a full MWE for your case, and here, we'll construct your `Object` type as a `struct` type (value type). Now, consider

```
// and for this example, assume your object is of value-type struct
struct Object {
    var someText = "default"

    mutating func doSomething() {
        someText += "_didSomething"
    }
}

// NOTE 1: if you want task(...) to play around with your dictionary, you
// need to pass your dictionary as an argument. In this case, I've used
// inout (see below).
func task(newId: Int, inout myDict: Dictionary<Int,Object>) {

    var newObj = myDict[newId]
    if (newObj == nil) {       
        newObj = Object()
        myDict[newId] = newObj // this copies newObj by _value_ to
                               // your dictionary

        newObj!.doSomething()   // This will not affect the previous 
                                //  _copy_ of newObj in your dictionary
    }  
}
```

Now, in the code above, you assign `newObj` to a new entry in your dictionary, but if `Object` is of value type, this is a value-copy assignment. This means that the following modifications to `newObj` are performed on a local instance of `Object`, living only in the scope of the `if` statement.

As expected, we see that the `.doSomething()` call on local `newObj` **after** value-assignment to your dictionary does not affect the dictionary entry.

```
var myDict = [Int:Object]()

task(1, myDict: &myDict) 
    // _inout_: myDict _copied_ to task(), copy modified in task,
    // and modified copy again _copied back_ to caller, myDict.

let isThereAStringInHere = myDict[1]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "default"
    // as expected, we get "default" and not "default_didSomething" here

let whatAboutHere = myDict[2]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "nope"
    // as expected, entry <2:Object> does not exist.
```

Now, the important part here was:

- (If you don't know what type you are dealing with, or just to be extra safe) always assume value-type assignments. If `Object` was of `class` type, the assignment `myDict[newId] = newObj` would have been by reference and the subsequent modification `newObj!.doSomething()` would have applied to the class instance in the dictionary `myDict`

---

Ok, after these notes, let's answer your questions.

**Question 1**

As has been mentioned in previous answer, as well as used in the discussion above, the nil coalescing operator can be used in cases as this. I'll add that, in this context, an `if let` clause might work just as well. We modify your `task(...)` function to be:

```
func taskNew(newId: Int, inout myDict: Dictionary<Int,Object>) {

    if let _ = myDict[newId] {
        // possibly do something with existing entry
    }
    else {
        // add new entry
        var myNewObj = Object()
        myNewObj.doSomething()
        myDict[newId] = myNewObj
    }
}

taskNew(2, myDict: &myDict)
let whatAboutNow = myDict[2]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "default_didSomething"
```

The `if let` clauses are very *"Swifty"*.

If you want to do something with your dictionary entry both for the use where it exist of where you create txt, you could replace the `taskNew` function above with this condensed one:

```
func taskNewShort(newId: Int, inout myDict: Dictionary<Int,Object>) {
    myDict[newId] = myDict[newId] ?? Object()
    myDict[newId]?.doSomething()
}

taskNewShort(3, myDict: &myDict)
let andNow = myDict[3]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "default_didSomething"
```

**Question 2**

The reason for the force unwrapping within your if clause if that your haven´t performed any explicit optional checking, meanwhile defining the myObj as

```
var newObj = myDict[newId] // <-- typ: Object? (optional Object)
```

Since `newObj` is of type optional, you'll have to unwrap at some point. Also, look at the value assignment to `newObj` in the if clause

```
newObj = Object() // assigns Object type to Object? type
                  // -> newObj is still optional (no down casting)
```

If you look at my answer to Question 1 above, you'll see that `newObj` is at no point an optional, and lives only in the clause where we know that a new `Object` instance will be added (copied) to your dictionary.

---

The full code for this answer follows, to simplify just copying into a playground for tracking what happens. Playgrounds are great for studying these kinds of behaviours.

```
struct Object {
    var someText = "default"

    mutating func doSomething() {
        someText += "_didSomething"
    }
}

func task(newId: Int, inout myDict: Dictionary<Int,Object>) {
    var newObj = myDict[newId]
    if (newObj == nil) {        // Question (1)
        newObj = Object()
        myDict[newId] = newObj

        newObj!.doSomething()   // Question (2)
    }
}

var myDict = [Int:Object]()
task(1, myDict: &myDict)
let isThereAStringInHere = myDict[1]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "default"
let whatAboutHere = myDict[2]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "nope"

func taskNew(newId: Int, inout myDict: Dictionary<Int,Object>) {
    if let _ = myDict[newId] {
        // possibly do something with existing entry
    }
    else {
        // add new entry
        var myNewObj = Object()
        myNewObj.doSomething()
        myDict[newId] = myNewObj
    }
}

taskNew(2, myDict: &myDict)
let whatAboutNow = myDict[2]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "default_didSomething"

func taskNewShort(newId: Int, inout myDict: Dictionary<Int,Object>) {
    myDict[newId] = myDict[newId] ?? Object()
    myDict[newId]?.doSomething()
}

taskNewShort(3, myDict: &myDict)
let andNow = myDict[3]?.someText ?? "nope" // -> "default_didSomething"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the value-type and other considerations. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
var dict: Dictionary<Int,Int> = [1:1,2:2]
let o = dict[3] ?? Int(3)
// now do something with o, it goes from you dict, or it is the 'new' one
// finaly you can update you dict with 'new' o
dict[3] = o
```

from apple docs

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.

Comment: Would you mind adding an explaination to your answer?

Comment: it is explained in comments in the example code. let element = dict[index] ?? Element() returns new Element if result of dict[index] is nil. so, you are sure that the element is valid Element value. If the value exist in your dictionary, you use the value. if value in the dictionary don't exist, you create a new one.

Comment: Well, someone flagged it and I had to moderate. Since it seems like a correct answer, maybe the reason why someone flagged it is the lack of enough explaination. Don't you think?

Comment: @dfri o can be almost everything, it doesn't matter if value or reference type. to do something with o doesn't means to modify the value (by the way, if you need to modify it, simply define it with var keyword). question (2) has no sense in my example, because o is non optional value (created with an constructor). please, check my notes above, and citation from apple docs. you can use every possible value or reference type the same way.

Comment: @dfri  var e = dictionary[index] ?? NewElement() is an equivalent of var e = dictionary[index] != nil ? dictionary[index]! : NewElement()

Comment: @dfri ii don't exactly know, what the guy want to do with the value received from his dictionary. i use immutable  value as much as possible in swift. maybe the guy need to pass the value to some function or something else. to do something with o doesn't means that you need to modify it.

Comment: @user3441734 ok, I see your point. I'll also remove my obsolete comments above in line with SO agenda on non-relevant comments

Answer (score 1):

I would write like this:

```
var myDict = [Int:Object]()

func task(newId: Int) {

    if myDict[newId] == nil {

        let newObj = Object()
        myDict[newId] = newObj

        newObj.doSomething()
    }
}
```

**Edit:** inside this block you'll have non-null `newObj`

```
if let newObj = myDict[newId] {
    newObj.doSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but `newObj` will be used outside of the `if` later again